# Database Tuning Advisor - Why does it give me no results?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, database-tuning

I am trying to use Database Tuning Advisor for the first time.

I believe I have resolved all permissions-related issues - needing SHOWPLAN, needing SELECT permission on 'DTA_tuninglog', etc.

Yet under 'Recommendations' it shows nothing.

It definitely runs and seems to be doing work, and there are no bad-looking errors in its output, but no recommendations are given.

I even tried creating a dummy database with a horrible query (lots of table scans) that would clearly be made better with an index, but it doesn't show any recommendations for that, either.

Perhaps my real question is: How do I know when DTA is actually working, versus me having some configuration issue that causes it to produce no output?

Does anybody have any pointers?

More Info:

I am using the defaults for the 'Tuning Options'

**Physical Design Structures (PDS) to use in database:**   Indexes

**Partitioning strategy to employ:**   No partitioning

**Physical Design Structures (PDS) to keep in database:**   Keep all existing PDS

Comment: Maybe your database is already perfect?

Comment: @Aaron - ha! Plus, as I mentioned, I tried it on a obviously-in-need-of-help test table, and still nothing...

Comment: can you post a pic of the options you have selected in the first scree please?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, I almost spit up my soda when I read that.

Comment: @kmcc049: I can't easily get a screenshot at the moment, but can post info. I added the 'Tuning Options' page info, if that's what you meant.

Comment: yeah, which tables did you select in the two parts where you select tables? Also how big was the workset you used for analysis? The tuning advisor tends to need quite a few queries to give any good advice if you've only got ten or so its not gonna give you anything.

Comment: @kmcc049: I selected the topmost checkbox for table, which made it auto-select all related tables in the lower section. Good to know about the data needing to be large. I think mine qualifies, it is from a 'stress test' run against the server.

Comment: did you record it in tuning mode? it one of the templates you select when using profiler?

Comment: @kmcc049 - Thanks for that; no I did not. After changing that, now DTA chugs for a long time and eventually throws an exception. I guess that's progress!

Comment: np, if I change that to an answer will you give me an accept then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have recorded your analysis data in tuning mode. To do this in SQL Server Profiler when you create the trace there is a drop down list with the label 'Use the template' change it from "Standard (default)" to "Tuning"

Comment: With the qualification that DTA still may choke on your data (as it likes to on mine :)  -  I have subsequently had better luck feeding DTA with a single .sql file containing the slow query in question.